# existence of antiderivative of a complex analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

> $(a)$ Show that there is a complex analytic function defined on the
>   set $U=\{z\in\mathbb{C} \ | \ |z|>4\}$ whose derivative is
>   $\displaystyle\frac{z}{(z-1)(z-2)(z-3)}$.
>
> $(b)$ Is there a complex analytic function on $U$ whose derivative is
>   $\displaystyle\frac{z^2}{(z-1)(z-2)(z-3)}$?

The problem clearly reduces to find a analytic function $f(z)$ on $U$ such that $f'(z)=\displaystyle\frac{z}{(z-1)(z-2)(z-3)}$. But if I integrate both sides over the contour of $U$, the RHS is analytic on $U$. So $f(z)=0$. But this result is too absurd to consider. Again same goes for $(b)$, but which is not the case since we have to prove no such $f$ would exist. I considered the CR-equations but the given function is too large to handle for this. What is the best approach for this problem? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why don't you just use partial fractions..?

Comment: it becomes -2/(z-2) + 1/[2(z-1)) + 3/[2(z-3)]

Comment: I believe there should be an easier method for this problem, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I used it above. But it yields no good result.

Comment: there's a shortcut lol. remove the (z-1) from the denominator, and then plug in z=1 to z/((z-2)(z-3) to get 1/2

Comment: this becomes your 1/(2(z-1))

Comment: for z=2, remove the (z-2) from the bottom and plug in z=2 to z/((z-1)(z-3)) and you'll get -2

Comment: same for z=3 and that'll complete the partial fraction decomp

Comment: Please write your comments as a answer. It will become easier for me to understand.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1216810/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2484774/42969 –  all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cdisplaystyle%5Cfrac%7Bz%7D%7B(z-1)(z-2)(z-3)%7D%24&p=1)